# Did cpu workload increased linearly in multithreading?

Tags: multithreading, cpu, cpu-usage

If a single thread cost 25% workload of a multi-core CPU, are 4 threads will fill the CPU?

Besides the 4 threads, can I do something else with the CPU?

Comment: 1) Sometimes yes, sometimes no.  2) Probably yes.  The OS allows different threads or applications to share the CPU.  If necessary, it will switch between them so that they all get a share (modulo priorities, etcetera).

Comment: This is very dependent of the workload/application. Thus, we cannot say if this is the case without more information. That being said, if your workload is to wait for some input and then compute it, then you may be able to improve the performance using multiple thread because 75% of the time could be to wait for the inputs. But again, some algorithms can be parallelized efficiently while some others cannot. There is no general rule.

Comment: The increase in performance depends greatly on your tasks. More precisely on the piece that can be parallelized and piece that cannot be parallelized. So for example if your task cannot be parallelized at all, 3 out of your 4 threads will do nothing, and your workload will stay at 25%. The problem is not simple. Perhaps you should also read about [Amdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a single thread uses 25% of the CPU, then what is using the other 75%?

If the answer is, *nothing* is using the other 75%—if the CPU is idle 75% of the time—then the single thread is not [*cpu-bound*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU-bound). That is to say, something other than the availability of CPU cycles is limiting the speed of the program.

What *is* blocking the thread? Probably the thread is awaiting some resource; messages from the network, disk I/O, user input, etc. Whatever it is, if there are at least four of them, and if your program can be structured to [*concurrently*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_computing) use four of them, then maybe running four threads will allow the program to run four times as fast.

An example would be, if your program is some kind of a server, and it spends a lot of time awaiting messages from clients, then adding more threads would allow it to simultaneously await more messages, and it would improve the throughput.

A counterexample would be if your program is processing data from a single disk file, and it spends most of its time awaiting data from the disk. Since there's only one disk, and the disk can only go so fast, adding more threads would not help in that case.